# Search form not working using class based view

Tags: django-class-based-views

I'm trying to create a search form but it's not working. Here are my codes:

```
class LocationSearchMixin(object):
    def get_queryset(self):
        q = self.request.GET.get('q')
        if q is None:
            return queryset


class StoreListView(LocationSearchMixin, ListView):
    model = Store


<form action="" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="q" />
    <button type="submit">search</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are something you must add in your LocationSearchMixin:

```
class LocationSearchMixin(object):
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(LocationSearchMixin, self).get_queryset()
        q = self.request.GET.get('q')
        if q is None:
            return queryset
        return queryset.filter(location__istartswith=q)
```